# KQL diferent tables

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

Hello guys this might be simple, but I'm trying to pull information from unrelated tables to create a rule that triggers when any of these two conditions are met.

Joining this two:

```
union SigninLogs, 
| where * contains "user"

SecurityEvent
|  where EventID == 4722
```

I tried, but the way I did it will only display the sign-ins or the event ID. I require it to bring the two different tables of information. Could someone point me in the right direction on this?

Is there a solution on how this join should be done?

Comment: Are you trying to get the result by combining both the tables with `union` operator where the respective conditions met?

Answer (score 0):

*Use below KQL query in sentinel workspace to combine two different tables according to your requirement.*

```bash
union SigninLogs, SecurityEvent
| extend EventType = iif(EventID == 4722, 'SecurityEvent', 'SigninLogs')
| where * contains "user" or EventID == 4722
```

[image]